# docker run command to install azure cli on windows container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container

I am trying to build a windows container with azure cli installed on it. below is my try. I am getting support from internet for linux but not for windows.
I am exactly looking for the code to create a windows container, install azure cli and install kubectl and upload powershell file and execute it at the starting of container and close the container after finishing.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1903
RUN -it mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli:2.9.1
WORKDIR /K8sDeploy
COPY deployk8s.ps1 .
ENV Storage_Account_Name=""
ENV Storage_Account_Key=""
ENV Storage_Account_Container=""

ENV PS_File=""
ENV Storage_Account_Subscription=""
ENTRYPOINT ["powershell.exe", "-executionpolicy" , "Bypass" , 
"C:\\K8sDeploy\\deployk8s.ps1","$Env:Storage_Account_Name" ,"$Env:Storage_Account_Key","$Env:ENV 
Storage_Account_Container=","$Env:PS_File","$Env:Storage_Account_Subscription"]
```

this powershell file containers az commands and kubectl commands.
I know that RUN `-it mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli:2.9.1` wont work but what is the windows version of this and if I am totally wrong.. please correct me.

Comment: When you say "won't work", is there an error? If so, update the post with said error.

Comment: hi ludo... error as follows '-it' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Basically i need a windows container with azure cli and kubectl installed in it.

Comment: So it's complaining about a commandline mistake. Update your post with the oririnal command you used to fire up the container. (something like "docker run -it IMAGENAME)

Comment: I am using visual studio code to build this image and push to repository(ACR). I havent find any internet support for command to install azure cli and kubectl. This is a build error which I cannot able to build image in the first place

Comment: Can imagine. I'm not using either (windows nor azure) so I think I can't help you any further. Can you try to manually build the image using commandline?

Comment: linux container works for me. i need to run az and kubectl commands to setup kubernetes cluster. Need to setup a container with powershell and azure cli and kubectl preinstalled in it.